# Why can I not plot using Python on repl.it

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-services, matplotlib

For practical reasons, I want to test a small piece of Pyton code on repl.it (webbased, so I do not need to install Python).

The code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
vec = np.array([1, 4, 3, -2])

plt.plot(time, vec)
```

gives following error:

```
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 16, in <module>
    plt.figure()
  File "/goval_modules/python35/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 535, in figure
    **kwargs)
  File "/goval_modules/python35/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 84, in new_figure_manager
    return new_figure_manager_given_figure(num, figure)
  File "/goval_modules/python35/matplotlib/backends/backend_tkagg.py", line 92, in new_figure_manager_given_figure
    window = Tk.Tk()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1868, in __init__
    self.tk = _tkinter.create(screenName, baseName, className, interactive, wantobjects, useTk, sync, use)
_tkinter.TclError: no display name and no $DISPLAY environment variable
exited with non-zero status
```

What does this mean?

Comment: Because an online website has no GUI server to display the plot on.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK, and is there any way to display or download the plot?

Comment: You may run your code at [try.jupyter.org](https://try.jupyter.org) where you get some inline (i.e. png) output.

Comment: @Karlo: you'd have to see what backends are supported, see https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`matplotlib` by default picks an *interactive backend*, showing the plot in a GUI; the default is to use TkInter. See [*What is a backend*](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend) in the matplotlib FAQ. That's not going to work when Python is run on a webserver, there is no GUI server to display this on.

You'll have to pick a non-interactive backend; `Agg` is supported and produces PNGs. Repl.it allows you to save files 'locally' <sup>(*)</sup>:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Agg')
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

time = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3])
vec = np.array([1, 4, 3, -2])

plt.plot(time, vec)
plt.savefig('graph.png')
```

When you run this, an extra `graph.png` tab appears that lets you download the result. See the [live demo](https://repl.it/HMK4/0); the above produces:

[image: matplotlib graph]

---

<sup>(*)</sup> For new scripts, enable *project mode* first by clicking on the *new file* icon. It looks like a document-with-plus-sign and sits underneath the 'settings' cog icon, above the line numbers of the editor.

Comment: If you re-run the code on repl, it may not update the graph.png file.  If you notice this behavior, delete the file before re-running.