# Rep-lit + Histograms + Matplotlib -- code works in Python but won't work on replit and there's no error messages

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib, replit

Reasking the same question that got closed:

I am a college professor who wants to teach a Python lesson without having students install Python on their computers. I am using this code from a colleague that I have tweaked. It works in Python. It is referencing two excel spreadsheets with coordinates and produces histograms for each.

Replit will not run the code. When I click "run" it begins installing the packages and then stops at some point. There are **no error messages** and the status screen goes blank, showing just a cursor. I checked my repository and there are no new images. I am assuming I am doing something wrong with either the Excel import + pandas or I am missing settings for running matplotlib online. Can someone help?

The github repository has the code + the 2 excel sheets. I absolutely want to run this on replit because each student is using their personal computer and it's too much for one introductory level class session to have them install Python.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/nsusmann/diydigarch)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43452136/why-can-i-not-plot-using-python-on-repl-it maybe

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!

First, I was trying to run the code without understanding the replit interface. I pasted it into main.py

Next, I had to install pip (did so using their packages interface), and after that it worked

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import openpyxl as pip

# Import excel files with the X and Y coordinates for flake distributions
# x and y coordinates were created in QGIS and exported into an excel file
r_basalt = pd.ExcelFile("Basalt-Right.xlsx")  # x and y coordinates for flakes knapped by a right hander
l_basalt = pd.ExcelFile("Basalt-Left.xlsx")  # x and y coordinates for flakes knapped by a left hander
#Creating dataframes for Sheet 1 in left and right hander flake coordinates
df_right = r_basalt.parse("Sheet1")
df_left = l_basalt.parse ("Sheet1")
#Identifying individual X and Y columns and turning them into lists
#Right
right_x = df_right["x"].tolist()
right_y = df_right["y"].tolist()
#Left
left_x = df_left["x"].tolist()
left_y = df_left["y"].tolist()
# Create empty grid
S = 200 #dimension of grid, 200 square centimeters
N = 10 #dimension of the grid lines, 10 centimeters apart
#min and max from nail coordinates recorded by the total station
x_max = 101.517
x_min = 98.761
y_max = 100.000
y_min = 97.798
# Right Hander Plot
plt.hist2d(right_x, right_y, bins=S)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("x (meters)")
plt.ylabel("y (meters)")
plt.title("Right-Hander Flakes")
plt.savefig("rh.jpeg")
#clear the plot so as not to retain the color ramp on next graph
plt.clf()
# Left Hander Plot
plt.hist2d(left_x, left_y, bins=S)
plt.colorbar()
plt.xlabel("x (meters)")
plt.ylabel("y (meters)")
plt.title("Left-Hander Flakes")
plt.savefig("lh.jpeg")
```